# How to bind data in ListBox as like gridview in mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, razor

i want to bind my data in List Box as like grid view in mvc

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectModel>

@{
     var grid = new WebGrid(
     source: Model,
     rowsPerPage: 4);
}
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "header",
    rowStyle: "row",
    footerStyle: "footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
    columns: grid.Columns (
    grid.Column("projectName"),
    grid.Column("ProjectID")
))
```

As like we do in this View.

Answer (score 0):

For Binding ListBox do like this,

```
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, 
                       Model.SomeSelectionList.Select(person=> 
                       new SelectListItem 
                       {
                           Text = person.Name, 
                           Value = person.Id, 
                           Selected = // some condition that returns true 
                       }),
                       new { Multiple = "multiple", size = "4"})
```